# C++ class destructor delete member if "owner"?

Tags: c++, reference-counting

I know in C++ that a pointer is just that: a pointer to a memory location, and there is no concept of "owners". But consider the following situation (not necessarily good code):

```
class A {
public:
    A(){}
    ~A()
    { if(myObject!=nullptr)
        delete myObject;
    }

    void createMember()
    {myObject=new CrazyCustomClass();}

    CrazyCustomClass *getMember()
    {return myObject;}
private:
    CrazyCustomClass *myObject=nullptr;
}
```

If it makes a difference, CrazyCustomClass does NOT have a copy constructor, as it makes no sense to copy it. So pretty straight forward - I have a class that, at some point after instantiation, may call `new` to instantiate a member of type `CrazyCustomClass *`

The problem is that if at some point I have a copy of `class A` created (which is fine - I want to be able to copy `class A`). When that *copy* is deleted, so is the object pointed to by the *original* class A instantiation. For example:

```
void StupidFunction(A *firstObject){
//This is NOT a real function, it simply illustrates the effect of a third-party library function
    //create a new object that is a copy of first object
    A secondObject(*firstObject);
    <do whatever with second object>
    //secondObject goes out of scope here and gets deleted.
}

A *firstObject=new A();
firstObject->createMember();
stupidFunction(firstObject);
CrazyCustomClass *customObject=firstObject.getMember(); //this is now an invalid pointer
```

In the above example, the `StupidFunction` is from a third-party library, the idea being that it gives a "temporary" copy of the object that you can work with without messing with the original object, which is good. `Class A` and `CrazyCustomClass` are both my code and can be changed at will. Unfortunately, when the "temporary" copy is deleted, the way I wrote my destructor causes problems.

My first thought was to use shared_ptr, something like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<CrazyCustomClass> sharedObject=std::make_shared<CrazyCustomClass>(new CrazyCustomClass);
```

...but that gave me an error when compiling:

> candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no
>   known conversion from 'CrazyCustomClass *' to 'const CrazyCustomClass'
>   for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *

and if I *do* dereference the argument with *, it gives me an error about the copy constructor of `"CrazyCustomClass"` being deleted, which is true - there is no sensible way to copy `CrazyCustomClass`.

So my question is: how can I refactor `class A` such that `myObject` gets properly deleted when `firstObject` goes out of scope, but *not* when any "temporary" copies of A get deleted?

Comment: "and there is no concept of "owners" - yes, there is.

Comment: You cannot use both `std::make_shared` and `new` together. The whole point of `make_shared` is so you don't need to `new` the object.

Comment: Read the [`make_shared` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) closely. You must pass the constructor's arguments and not a pointer.

Comment: Pick up a copy of [Scott Meyer's book](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996) on _Effective Modern C++_.

Comment: @alterigel So perhaps my original approach of shard_ptr (which I have never used before, they did not exist when I was learning C++) was correct, I just did it wrong? I'll have to try again.

Comment: {
    std::shared_ptr<A> sharedObject=std::make_shared<A>();
    sharedObject->createMember();
    stupidFunction(sharedObject.get());
    }

Comment: It's in the docs. Basically, `make_shared<T>(Args...)` forwards its arguments to one of `T`'s constructors.

Comment: ibrewster, you may be misinterpreting Neil's comment.  C++ has the concept of ownership, but raw pointers enforce no ownership. The various smart pointers enforce ownership each in their own way.

Comment: @user4581301 That makes sense. Back when I was learning C++, there was no concept of "smart Pointers", so this is new to me.

Comment: @ibrewster If you want to express that a type has no copy constructor, you can delete it explicitly with `= delete`. For example `A(const A&) = delete;`. Then do the same for the assignment operator. Anyone who tries to copy an instance of `A` will now get a compiler error instead of undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not really anything to do with smart pointers - for example, a class like std::string "owns" the dynamically allocated array of char that contains the string representation, but the pointer that "owns" it (a member variable of std::string)  has historically at least not been a smart pointer.

Comment: @ibrewster "*Unfortunately, when the "temporary" copy is deleted, the way I wrote my destructor causes problems.*" - `A` does not follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It has a compiler-generated copy constructor that merely copies the `myObject` pointer as-is, rather than making a copy of `myObject` for the temporary to work with. You need to provide such a copy constructor (and copy assignment operator), eg: `A(const A &a) { if (a.myObject) myObject = new CrazyCustomClass(*(a.myObject)); }` Or disable them, like François suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `shared_ptr` is in fact a solution to this problem, however the code as attempted in the original question is incorrect. There are two (at least) different ways to initialize a `shared_ptr` (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279669.aspx). First, you can do it by using `new` as a constructor argument:

```
shared_ptr<CrazyCustomClass> myObject(new CrazyCustomClass)
```

Secondly, and this is the generally preferred method, you can use the make_shared function (as attempted in the original post), which takes not the `new` object, but the *arguments* to be passed to the object constructor, in this case nothing:

```
shared_ptr<CrazyCustomClass> myObject=make_shared<CrazyCustomClass>()
```

The original code simply got these two methods mixed up, thus the errors about copy constructor: it was trying to instantiate a new `CrazyCustomClass` object with a pointer to a `CrazyCustomClass` object as the constructor argument.

Once using a `shared_ptr`, the `delete` in the destructor must be removed.

Tip of the hat to @tkausl and @alterigel for pointing out the error in the comments on the question!